# Seaborn: How to replace index with text in X-Axis in barplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataset with `category` column which has integer values representing class label i.e 0,1,2.....

I have separate file which contains text labels for that category i.e against index 0, it contains `classA` and so on. I want to plot a barplot using seaborn with following code.

```
import seaborn as sns
train_df = pd.read_csv("unclean_text.csv", sep='\t')
label_text = pd.read_csv("labels.csv")
is_dup = train_df['category'].value_counts()

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
sns.barplot(is_dup.index, is_dup.values, alpha=0.8, color=color[1])
plt.show()
```

It correctly plots the barplot for frequency of each class.

[image]

But I want text labels on the x-axis instead of index values that are in `label_text`, which is also a column vector of length 19 (0-18). How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sns.barplot()` will return the axis for the plot. You can use this to set your tick labels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

color = ['r', 'g', 'b']
train_df = pd.read_csv("unclean_text.csv", sep='\t')
label_text = pd.read_csv("labels.csv")
is_dup = train_df['category'].value_counts()

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = sns.barplot(is_dup.index, is_dup.values, alpha=0.8, color=color[1])
ax.set_xlabel('Category')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Occurrences')
ax.set_xticklabels(label_text['labels'], rotation='vertical', fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

This assumes `labels.csv` is something like:

```
labels
cat0
cat1
cat2
cat3
cat4
cat5
cat6
cat7
cat8

etc..
```

Giving you an output:

[image: graph plot with labels for x axis]

Comment: This is an answer, but it's not the correct answer.